# Is a Chinese multiple-entry, 6-month tourist visa (L) available to a Sri Lankan citizen?

Tags: china, tourist-visas, sri-lankan-citizens

I'm a Sri Lankan passport holder planning to travel to Mainland China in May and a few more times in the following six months.

Comment: @pnuts might be worth elaborating WHY you suggest they change their plans.

Comment: What is your premise? Have you had Chinese visa before, and in the same passport?

Comment: @mts Yeah. I visited Shanghai last month

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: **yes**. The visa form from the Chinese embassy in your country has this option.

More complex answer: **maybe**. Not all embassies want to immediately issue a multiple entry visa, and you need to meet the requirements to be able to get one. Based on my own experience with China, I was only able to get a multiple entry visa if I had visited China at least 3 times in the last 2 years (but I'm no Sri Lankan resident, so who knows different rules apply to you).

Also, it is quite common that you need more documentation as proof than what is listed on the website. Sometimes the website doesn't list any documentation, but you need plenty of proof. The best solution is to call the Chinese embassy and ask them.